# can't install vpython on linux mint

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint

i tried installing vpython on linux mint 19

using this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install vpython
```

the error i get:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'


Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9f9b5ihc/vpython/
```

Comment: I think you need to install python-setuptools and python3-setuptools first.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually quite clear answer to your question in the error message you get from python:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'` and it basically means that this module is required to complete the operation you try to perform, but it is missing in your system.

You can easily install it using `apt-get`:

`apt-get install -y python3-setuptools` for python3

`apt-get install -y python-setuptools` for python

Then try to run your command again and it should work.